# Logic Apps and long running Azure Function (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I have a Function App written in Powershell, that is being triggered by Logic Apps and that sends back to Logic Apps following response:

```
 Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body = [ordered]@{
        "Subject" = "$scriptName executed successfully."
        "MailTemplate" = "$template"
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    })
```

The problem is that this Function App can sometimes even run up to 10 minutes, and in that case it returns an error. I saw that a Webhook activity can be implemented in order to resolve the issue, but in that case the Function App would have to return a response twice - once at the very beginning with a status code 200, and once at the very end - which is not possible using the above method, since you can have only one OutputBinding in the code. How can this be resolved? I also tried adding an "until" loop into my Logic App, but this still gives me the same error.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the usage of the webhook action.  It provides a URL that you send the response to, it doesn't continue to your normal "response" in your code, it continues when you send a HTTP request to the endpoint it provides you.

Comment: HXTTP a client send a request and the server responds.  You code is on the server.  Your code is failing because the connection already closed probably due to the response already being sent.  Make sure there isn't another path in your code that is either closing the connection or responding.